# Symfony Exception while trying to subscribe to an existing event

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

As the title says i want to extend a email entity so i'm trying to subscribe to the MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER event. When the user submit the form i want to extend the outgoing email. Currently im struggeling with this exception

This is the exception:

```
Argument 1 passed to RegistrationExtension\Subscriber\RegisterExtensionSubscriber::onCustomRegister() must be an instance of Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent, instance of Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\DataMappingEvent given, called in /app/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php on line 126
```

And here my code :)

```
<?php
namespace RegistrationExtension\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEntity;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;

class RegisterExtensionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array{
        return [
            CustomerEvents::MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER => 'onCustomRegister'
        ];
    }
    public function onCustomRegister(EntityLoadedEvent $event , SalesChannelContext $context){
         /**
         * @var EntityRepositoryInterface $mailTypeRepository
         * @var EntityRepositoryInterface $mailRepository
         */
        $mailTypeRepository = $this->container->get('mail_template_type.repository');
        $mailRepository = $this->container->get('mail_template.repository');
        
        $mailEntity = $mailTypeRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template_type.technicalName', "customer_register")),
            $context->getContext()
        );

        $mailTypeId = $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()->getId();


        $mailEntity = $mailRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template.mailTemplateTypeId', $mailTypeId)),
            $context->getContext()
        );
        
        //$mailEntity->getEntities()->setContentHtml("test");
        $mail = $mailEntity->getEntities();

        return $this->renderStorefront(
            '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/address/index.html.twig',[
                'page' => $context,
                'mailEntity' => $mail
            ]
        );

        /** @var CustomerEntity $customerRegisEvent */
        foreach ($event->getEntities() as $customerRegisEvent) {
            $customerRegisEvent->addExtension('custom_struct', new RegisterStruct());
        } 
    }
}
```

Any help is apreciated :)

*[EDIT]*

```
<?php
namespace RegistrationExtension\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEntity;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent;

class RegisterExtensionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array{
        return [
            \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onCustomRegister'
        ];
    }
    public function onCustomRegister(\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent $event){
        /** @var CustomerEntity $customerRegisEvent */
        foreach ($event->getMailStruct() as $customerRegisEvent) {
            $customerRegisEvent->addExtension('custom_struct', new RegisterStruct());
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need another event

```
\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent:class => 'onCustomRegister'
```

and also you need to change the definition of `onCustomRegister` method

try

```
public function onCustomRegister(\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent $event)
```

After that, you can get customer inside the method by
$event->getCustomer() and context by $event->getSalesChannelContext()

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply :) I've tried what you said, (you can see it in the edit part). Still throwing the same erro :S Do you have any idea? Or could you explain a bit what the error seems to be?

Comment: You should also change name of event in `getSubscribedEvents ` method
Change `CustomerEvents::MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER` to 
\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent:class

Comment: Oh ok sorry my fault. Well it does not throw an exception great :D. But the listener seems not to trigger. Any clue?

Comment: As you got an exception before, it should be still triggered.
How do you understand that it is not triggered?

Comment: I search for the event in the Symfony profiler. And it is in the "Not called listener" tab :) (Btw thank you really for your help :))

Comment: It can be not triggered if DoubleOptInRegistration option is enabled

Comment: Hmm i've checked it but the option was disabled. also tryied to enable and disable but without luck :)